# Trying to access a NSTextView from another class

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm creating a NSTextView in my AppController.h:

```
 @interface AppController : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSTextView *texto;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextView *texto;

@end
```

After connected and properly checked, I'm trying to set a texto for this TextView from another class (AppMenu.m), but with no luck:

```
#import "AppController.h"

- (IBAction)setText:(id)sender {
        AppController *appControl = [[AppController alloc] init];
        [[appControl texto] setString:@"Hello"];
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: I'm trying to set a text for a NSTextView declared in another class.

Comment: You cannot access the Object which you done own. To access the NSTextView object in another class you have to use delegate method.(or) use Singleton Method to access that object

Comment: @Lucas Veiga that's not the problem. That's the goal to be achieved. What is **the problem**? What do you mean by 'it's not working'?

Comment: @H2CO3 He want to set Text to the label from another class, the problem is He is not able to complete that

Comment: @Sumanth so there's a compiler erro, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Appmenu creates a new instance of texto, a local one just for appmenu (with the same properties), and not setting properties on the one actually in appcontroller. If you try debugging, you'll see that the two texto objects have different memory pointers.

You could make appcontroller the delegate for appmenu and create a 'setTextoProps' method which can pass data from appmenu over to appcontroller.

You could also make an instance of storyboard.appcontroller and set data directly  with something like

```
Appcontroller *controller  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifi er:@"appcontroller"]; 

[self.controller.texto setText...];
```

Comment: A lot of answers deal with delegates, so I won't go in to detail on that since I'm writing from my cellphone

Answer (score 0):

When you call `alloc` you create a **new** object.  What you need is a reference to the `AppController` that already exists.

(I'm assuming the text view is already displayed by an `AppController` object before you execute the code that tries to change its field.)

Comment: I can't tell you details without knowing how your application is structured, but the basic idea is to give the AppMenu a property that points to an instance of AppController and then connect them, either when they are created or in a xib or...again, it depends on the app.  The main point is that these are individual **objects** and they don't automatically share their variables with other objects of the same kind.

Comment: you have to pass value to AppController class at the time of pushing it.